# SharePoint workflow if/else if

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

[image] I created a simple SharePoint 2010 workflow for the purpose below:
 - when a new item is added, send an email to notify item approver
 - when a new item is rejected, send an email to notify item created by

Somehow the workflow is only working for notifying approver not the created by. I'm not sure when the workflow finds the first logic is true, then it stops the second part of the logic(else if)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You put the else if condition to the wrong place, the else-if branch should be with the condition "IF Approval Status equals pending". Please change your workflow like this, it should work:

[image]